# Creating a log axis in a 100% stacked column chart in R with ggplot

Tags: r, excel, graph, plot, ggplot2

I have data in percentages. I would like to use ggplot to create a graph, but I cannot get it to work like I would like.  Since the data is very skewed a simple stacked column doesn't work well because the really small values don't show up.  Here is a sample set:

```
    Actual  Predicted
a   0.5     5
b   9.5     5
c   90      90
```

On the left is an excel plot and on the right is R-ggplot

[image: Excel][image: Rplot]

The problem is that in R the columns do not stack up to be even.

Here is my R code:

```
a = c("a","b","c","a","b","c")
b = c("Actual","Actual","Actual","Predicted","Predicted","Predicted")
c = c(0.5,2.5,97,0.2,2.2,97.6)
c = c+1

dat = data.frame(Type=a, Case=b, Percentage=c)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Case, y=Percentage, fill=Type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_y_log10()
```

*In both Excel and R I do a +1 to deal with numbers 0-1, so the y-axis is off slightly

If I use:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Case, y=Percentage, fill=Type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "fill") + scale_y_log10()
```

The total heights match, however the two blue portions do not match in size (they are both 90%)

[image]

Comment: This question could also be migrated to Crossvalidated.

Answer (score 5):

Just because two sets of numbers add up to the same value (103 in this case) doesn't mean the sum of the logs will add up to the same value! When you stack the bars without "fill" you get them different heights because the sums of the logs of the values are different. When you then scale it all to the same height you have to squash the blue boxes down by different rates and so they look different.

The Excel bar chart is deliberately misleading. The left red bar is the same size as the blue bar above it but represents a value of about a tenth of the blue bar. You can't make a barchart on a log scale of proportions - its just wrong.

There is a brilliant way to show small numbers without losing them or misrepresenting them. Its an amazing visualisation technique called 'writing the numbers in a table'.

Comment: Yes I realized it was a log(a+b) != log(a)+log(b) thing.

The excel version is visually misleading but numerically correct.  What you cant see (I shrank it too much) is the the center tick is 10%, so basically the left red bar runs from 0 to 10% which is correct.

Comment: Also 'writing the numbers in a table' is not a visualization.  When I have a 10x30 table NOBODY is going to look at it.  You wont be able to see patterns and inconsistencies.

Comment: Plot the data as points, not bars. Think about the story you are trying to tell. Are you trying to talk about the difference in actual and predicted? Plot the difference. etc

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work like excel.  Like Spacedman said, the plot is visually misleading, but numerically correct.  The reason is that we want to compare bar segment actual height, when numerically you need to look at the y-axis start and end values.  Its similar to bar charts that don't have a y-axis minimum of zero.  Here is an [example](http://www.b-eye-network.com/view/index.php?cid=2468).

I am not sure if I will use the method for visualizing my data, but I had to figure it out.

Here is the result:

[image]

Here is the code (I might clean it up as a function that can be called when you assign the y values in ggplot).

```
a = c("a","b","c","a","b","c")
b = c("Actual","Actual","Actual","Predicted","Predicted","Predicted")
c = c(0.5,9.5,90,5,5,90)
c = c+1
dat = data.frame(Type=a, Case=b, Percentage=c, Cumsum_L=c, Cumsum=c, Norm=c)
for(i in 1:length(dat$Percentage)){
    cumsum=0
    for(j in 1:i){
        if(dat$Case[j]==dat$Case[i]){
            cumsum=cumsum+(dat$Percentage[j])
        }
    }
    dat$Cumsum_L[i]=cumsum-dat$Percentage[i]
    dat$Cumsum[i]=cumsum
    if(dat$Cumsum_L[i]==0){
        dat$Cumsum_L[i]=1
    }
    dat$Norm[i] = log(dat$Cumsum[i])-log(dat$Cumsum_L[i])
}
intervals = seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 10)
intervals_log = log(intervals)
intervals_log[1]=0

ggplot(dat, aes(x=Case, y=Norm, fill=Type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(name="Percent",breaks = intervals_log, labels=intervals )
```

*I also need to fix the end points +1 kinda thing.

**I also might be butchering maths.